# Should i upgrade to town hall 8?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm late town hall 7 with maxed cannons,archer towers,Wizard towers and Mortars my air defenses are level 4 which i will upgrade them very soon to max. my walls are level 6 mostly. should i max my walls and Tesla before going to Town hall 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always max everything before going to the next TH. So you will be superior to more other TH 8's who do not do that. Except when you are TH 8 or above then you are able to not upgrade your walls to the max (if you want to, because it takes A LOT of time, still don't advice it).

Comment: Glad to hear about the walls being considered optional. No way I am going to do all of them at TH8, even the building upgrades take ages already. Walls would take me months.

Comment: Yes, it is a grind.

Comment: I disagree about the walls. They're such a critical component in protecting your resources from raiders and upgrading them is such a huge jump in HP. Yes, it'll take a lot of gold/time, but that's all time you can also spend upgrading your troops with the elixir you'd otherwise not be using.

Comment: I also upgrade my walls to the max, that is why i said i don't advice you to not upgrade them. i only mentioned the option to not upgrade them because i see a lot of people not upgrading their walls (certainly above TH8).

Comment: thanks for advice Bob i will max my walls and then i will upgrade to Town Hall 8